# MySQL Error, Unknown reason

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have been reading this query now for about 20 minutes and I cannot see what is wrong with it.

```
SELECT   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS addressbook_people.first_name,
         addressbook_people.last_name                     ,
         addressbook_people.preferred_name                ,
         addressbook_companies3.name                      ,
         addressbook_people.url                           ,
         addressbook_groups5.name                         ,
         addressbook_people.telephone1                    ,
         addressbook_people.telephone2                    ,
         addressbook_people.telephone3                    ,
         addressbook_people.email1                        ,
         addressbook_people.email2                        ,
         addressbook_people.fax1                          ,
         addressbook_people.fax2                          ,
         root_countries13.name                            ,
         root_territories14.name                          ,
         root_cities15.name                               ,
         addressbook_people.address1                      ,
         addressbook_people.zip_postal1                   ,
         addressbook_people.po_box                        ,
         root_countries19.name                            ,
         root_territories20.name                          ,
         root_cities21.name                               ,
         addressbook_people.address2                      ,
         addressbook_people.zip_postal2
FROM     addressbook_people
WHERE    (
                  (
                           addressbook_people.first_name     LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.last_name      LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.preferred_name LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_companies3.name       LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.url            LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_groups5.name          LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.telephone1     LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.telephone2     LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.telephone3     LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.email1         LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.email2         LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.fax1           LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.fax2           LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       root_countries13.name             LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       root_territories14.name           LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       root_cities15.name                LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.address1       LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.zip_postal1    LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.po_box         LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       root_countries19.name             LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       root_territories20.name           LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       root_cities21.name                LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.address2       LIKE '%a%'
                  OR       addressbook_people.zip_postal2    LIKE '%a%'
                  )
         )
         LEFT JOIN addressbook_companies AS addressbook_companies3
         ON       addressbook_people.company_id = addressbook_companies3.id
         LEFT JOIN addressbook_groups AS addressbook_groups5
         ON       addressbook_people.group_id = addressbook_groups5.id
         LEFT JOIN root_countries AS root_countries13
         ON       addressbook_people.country1 = root_countries13.id
         LEFT JOIN root_territories AS root_territories14
         ON       addressbook_people.territory1 = root_territories14.id
         LEFT JOIN root_cities AS root_cities15
         ON       addressbook_people.city1 = root_cities15.id
         LEFT JOIN root_countries AS root_countries19
         ON       addressbook_people.country2 = root_countries19.id
         LEFT JOIN root_territories AS root_territories20
         ON       addressbook_people.territory2 = root_territories20.id
         LEFT JOIN root_cities AS root_cities21
         ON       addressbook_people.city2 = root_cities21.id
ORDER BY LTRIM(addressbook_people.url)DESC
LIMIT    0, 10
```

This is the output of my filter for a data table. So ignore the fact that i'm looking for like 'a'

I use PHPMyAdmin, when executing the SQL in a Query via the Web Management Console I receive the following error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'LEFT JOIN addressbook_companies AS addressbook_companies3 ON
> addr' at line 54

I've checked the line, it's the beginning of my joins. I don't see a problem.. Can someone please help? I've never been any good with SQL.

Comment: There isn't perchance a limit on the query length in the web management console, is there?  That's a pretty long query.

Comment: i'd like to see how much time this query will need to be executed on table with 1.000.000 rows, which is not that much :)

Comment: it's actually not that bad. Right now I have 6000 rows and it executes in a fraction of a second. It's part of ajax result filtering. I see very little delay, so short I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: Also it should be mentioned this is only being developed to support 10-20 thousand rows

Comment: **Never assume that you'll only be developing for a fixed number of items. You never know how widely used the code might become in the future.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do your `JOIN`s before your `WHERE` clause

Comment: @Hughes, yes they are I noticed my slip right after I posted.

Comment: Just to clarify: The WHERE comes AFTER the JOINS, not before.

Comment: Yes! I did not know that! Learn something new every day! Works like a charm now. Thanks!